How to restore a destroyed vampire as a vampire?
A vampire has been slain, i.e destroyed, through use of holy magics and substances, though the body is still intact.  However, there are those who would want to restore it to its unlife, since the destroyed vampire was pregnant (thanks to a combination of sucking the blood of a volunteer blood donor and a Ring of Endure Elements which has been ruled as functioning by magically maintaining a normal human body temperature), and the father is in love, and believes that the probably half-vampire child either won't survive the death and resurrection of its mother, or if it does, won't be a half-vampire, and that the mother won't remember her years as a vampire and by extension, won't remember him.
As I understand it, undead can be affected by Resurrection or True Resurrection, but those spells will restore the vampire to its pre-vampire living state.  This is unacceptable since the people who would like to restore this pregnant vampire to its unlife don't trust other vampires.  Wish should be a possibility, but it is very expensive. Miracle won't be possible, since the deities involved won't support such a use of the spell.
Is there any way beyond variants of Resurrection and making the resurrected person a vampire again, or a Wish to restore a destroyed vampire to unlife?

The revive undead spell (Spell Compendium, p. 175) will:

...restore animation to an undead creature destroyed by hit point loss (even a zombie or skeleton, which can't normally be reanimated once destroyed). You can revive a destroyed undead creature that has been inactive for up to one day per caster level. In addition, the subject's animating spirit must be free and willing to return. If the subject's animating spirit is not willing to return, the spell does not work; therefore, subjects that want to revive receive no saving throw.

This may or may not work for your purposes; I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "use of holy magics and substances".  If the vampire was destroyed by turning, then revive undead won't work, since:

An undead that has been destroyed by a turning effect can't be revived by this spell.

The spell also requires the body to be intact, but that won't be a problem for you.

No, not turned. Ravages (as BoED).
